# Your opinion on the "volume" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [volume](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/volume) tag is currently applied to nine questions:

- Four of them use it to describe mounted disks
- Five of them use it to describe audio sound levels

Tags with multiple meanings are barely more useful than no tag at all.

Any suggestions on which of these should be renamed, and to what?

---

*Update:*

I don't think we need a [data-volume](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-volume) tag, as it looks like [disk-space](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disk-space) is sufficient.

I went through the posts and made some edits:

- Where `volume` referred to audio levels, I added the already-existing [audio](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio) tag
- Where `volume` referred to mounted disks, I added the already-existing [hard-drive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-drive) tag

Once I'd done that, it appeared that Jeff was right that we may not need the `volume` tag at all, so I removed it from each.

Should [volume](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/volume) be added to the blacklist?

Comment: Please notice volumes are not necessarily hard drives: they can be CDs, pen drives, DMGs, etc.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure this tag needs to exist at all. Would anyone browse just questions with [volume](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/volume) ? For what purpose? Under what circumstances?

I think [disk](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disk) and [audio](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio) are better general tags.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps break it out to...

- `audio-volume` (Maybe `sound-volume` is more common?).
- `disk-volume`, which isn't very common, but I've seen it used here and there.
- `data-volume`, which can be used for questions about managing hard drive space.

It would be nice if there was a default we could place via the tag wikis, but 4/5 is too close to call

Answer (score -2):

What are the down sides to allowing 'volume' to be used both ways?  If am looking for audio-style volume, then I can search for 'volume'.  Then I see that it is ambiguous when I see the results, and I add another tag "audio" to further limit the scope.  I hope it's not a knee-jerk reaction that a tag should not have two different but specific meanings (think homonym)

Comment: A tag should *not* have more than one meaning. Tags are meant to catergorize content, not place it in arbitrary buckets.